ESP32 GDB debugging error on M1 mac - dyld[]: missing symbol called
I've followed the espressif docs for ESP-IDF on my M1 Mac, and can build and flash the device fine.
I'm using the esp-prog for debugging, and have followed the espressif JTAG debugging instructions.
Unfortunately, when I try to launch GDB I get the error dyld[]: missing symbol called. Fatal signal: Abort trap: 6.
And I'm told to report this to GDB as a bug.
I haven't been able to find much info on esp-prog use with arm64 macs, or this error, so I'm quite stuck.
Any help is greatly appreciated!!

What's in your gdbinit file, if any?
I ran into a similar error when trying to setup debugging in Clion.
The solution was to set the Debugger binary xtensa-esp32-elf-gdb in the Toolchain settings, and then select it in the Run Configuration.
Instead of writing -file-exec-and-symbols build/main.elf in the gdb console just pass the symbol file as command line argument:
xtensa-esp32-elf-gdb -x gdbinit ../build/main.elf
